# how to process string Time to ISO format in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have logic app in that im taking value of time using below expression from sql.

```
formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'Pacific Standard Time'),'HHmmss')
```

value I get is `234310` now I want to substract 3 minutes from this time for that I write below expression.

For above as @Meyer suggested i have solution like i can subtract first and then do formatting but in other cases i got `002322` value from sql table in this case if i convert and subtract it gives value as `2322` which is wrong value. what could be the solution in that scenario how to subtract 3 minutes from `002322`

```
subtractFromTime(formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'Pacific Standard Time'),'HHmmss'),3,'Minute')
```

but getting error -

```
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Initialize_variable' inputs at line '1' and column '3443': 'In function 'subtractFromTime', the value provided for date time string '003417' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.
```

I tried even `Date Time Action`

[image]

Comment: You can do this with Date Time action:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Problem-with-Subtract-from-Time-in-months/td-p/276357

Comment: but i do not want date in that could you please help me with my example?

Comment: i tried getting same error 
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Subtract_from_time' at line '1' and column '3443': 'In function 'subtractfromtime', the value provided for date time string '012239' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.

Comment: Something is strange here. What is 234310? It's not epoch. formatDateTime should return a string: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime

formatDateTime('03/15/2018 12:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
And returns this result: "2018-03-15T12:00:00"

Comment: its a value from this expression -
formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'Pacific Standard Time'),'HHmmss')

Comment: "234310" is a custom string.
subtractFromTime requires a timestamp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#subtractFromTime

subtractFromTime('<timestamp>', <interval>, '<timeUnit>', '<format>'?) 
subtractFromTime('2018-01-02T00:00:00Z', 1, 'Day')

Comment: ohh i see could you please help me with the same value?

Comment: subtractFromTime(utcNow(), 3, 'Minute')  returns the desired time. Afterwards you can format it

Comment: thanks for utcnow() one more issue is from another step i got that timestamp value from sql table like format "234310" for such scenarios how to substarct 3 minutes?

Comment: Convert "234310" to int and subtract 3: int('<value>')

Comment: when convert int if value is `003411` it is giving as `3411` because of this value API giving error now  :( anything i can do for this? thanks in advance

Comment: After subtracting you have to convert it so string including leading zeros

Comment: let me try that as well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem like this and it seems to be able to get the result you want:

```
formatDateTime(convertFromUtc(addMinutes(utcNow(), -3),'Pacific Standard Time'),'HHmmss')
```

You can substract 3 minutes first, and then convert your time.

I did a test, it seems no problem:

[image]